# Why is the graph of $x-1>y$ like this?

Tags: graphing-functions

Why is the graph of $x-1>y$ like this? I cannot get it intuitively. Can someone help? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I meant to ask that why all points below that half plane give $x-1>y$?

Comment: Perhaps look at the equivalent inequality $y<x-1$.

Comment: Check some?  So, $(4,-1)$ gives $x-1 = 3$ which is indeed greater than $-1$.

Comment: @Randall how does checking some will verify us that all points satisfy that inequality?

Comment: @Aqua it doesn't, but it builds your *intuition* on why this is correct

Comment: @Randall Oh ok. Is there a method to ensure that all points below that half plane will satisfy the inequality?

Comment: $x$ approaching $+\infty$ is to the right, while $y$ approaching $+\infty$ is upward.

Comment: Look at the vertical line through $x=a$. The points satisfying $y<x-1$ with $x=a$ are those on the vertical line and below the line $y=x-1$.

Comment: Are you comfortable with coming up with a visual representation of $x-1>y$ for a specific value of $y$?  For example, coming up with a visual representation of $x-1>0$?  Coming up with a visual representation of $x-1>1$, for $x-1>2$ and so on?  Now... think of these as horizontal slices of your final graph and stack them up onto one another and generalize to arbitrary $y$ as opposed to specific individual values of $y$...

Comment: I am still confused how you are going about it.. Can you please explain in an easier way?

Comment: I asked several leading questions.  Focus on the second for now...  Are you or are you not comfortable coming up with a visual representation of $x-1>0$?

Comment: We have $y<x-1$. First draw the graph of $y=x-1$, it is a line contains all the points $(x,y)$ so that value of $y$ on each point is equal to $x-1$. Now, value of $y$ in any point above the line is greater than value of $y$ on the line  (which is equal to $x-1$) and vise versa. So $y>x-1$ denotes all the point above the line $y=x-1$ and $y<x-1$ denotes all the points below that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in terms of horizontal slices and specific values of $y$.  When $y$ is specifically equal to $0$ the inequality becomes $x-1>0$ or rearranged, $x>1$.  So, think of graphing $x>1$ on the number line.

Do the same for when $y=1$ this becomes $x-1>1$ or rearranged $x>2$.

Imagine doing this for "*many*" such values of $y$ and coming up with "*many*" stacked inequalities on the numberline.

[image: stacked inequalities]

Now, make sure that each horizontal slice is at the height corresponding to it's respective $y$-value